# How to list all instances of an association field in the index page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models in a has_one belongs_to relationship:

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :machine
end


class Machine < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :facility
end
```

When creating a new machine, I have a collection_select to save a facility:

```
<%= collection_select(:machine, :facility_id, Facility.all, :id, 
:facility_name, prompt: true) %>
```

In the index page, when I try to list all the machines, I get an error:

```
undefined method `facility_name'
```

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-hover 
table-sm ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Facility Name</th>
     .
     .
     .
   <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <% @machines.each do |machine| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= machine.facility.facility_name %></td>
   .
   .
   .
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', machine %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_machine_path(machine) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', machine, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 
   'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Comment: do you have `facility_name` field in Facility model?

Comment: You get `undefined method 'facility_name'` on what? `#<Facility ...>` OR `nil:NilClass`

Comment: Most probably `machine.facility` returns `nil` in your list page.

Comment: Yes I have `facility_name` field in Facility Model.

Comment: Yes I get it on `nil:NilClass` `undefined method `facility_name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Or could the error be in the `index` action?

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing `collection_select`, insted use only select `select` as you just want to save the id of the `Facility` in `Machine` not the array of ids.

try some thing like this:

```
<%= f.select :facility_id, options_for_select(Facility.all.pluck(:facility_name, :id),:selected => f.object.facility_id), {:prompt => 'Select facility'}%>
```

here f is the instance of machine during the create action

Comment: Thanks, but the facility_id saves well

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok, even it seems you are not using [model object helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects).

Maybe records are not saved for any reason? I guess: strong params permission?

Try in console `Machine.select(:id, :facility_id)` to check if record exists and all have the associated `facility_id`:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Machine id: 1, facility_id: 1>, #<Machine id: 2, facility_id: 2>, #<Machine id: 3, facility_id: 3>, ....
```

Anyway, post the complete error message.

---

Just to know, your association for `Facility` is `has_one :machine`, but with the form it seems that you can assign the same facility to many machines.

Comment: The complete error message is `undefined method `facility_name' for nil:NilClass` I am not sure whether the association could be cause of the error since the error persists even when I change to `has_many`

Comment: You are right the association is not the origin of the error, it was just a note. But from the error messages it seems there are no records or incomplete records. Did you try in the console to check the content of the tables?

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on this, I realized the facility_id field in the table was blank! I now have a better idea on debugging this `nil:NilClass undefined method` errors.

Thanks!